# Angular typeahead not populating content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have some serious troubles using typeahead in angular.js. The data is not populated even tough i can see in the function linked with the typehead attribute, that the objects are exiting

Relevant part of my controller:

```
angular.module('rechnungCtrl', ['rechnungService','kundeService'])

.controller('RechnungController', function(Rechnung, Kunde, $route, $routeParams, $location, $http) {

vm.searchKunde = function(val) {

        Kunde.search(val)
            .success(function(data) {
                //When seting a breakpoint in chrome here i can see that the data is correctly loaded from the REST Service
                return data;
        });
    }
```

Relevant part of my view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="kunde" placeholder="Kunde" typeahead="obj.vorname for obj in ctrl.searchKunde($viewValue)" ng-model="ctrl.selectedKunde">
```

Usage of the module

```
angular.module('EasyApp', ['ngBootbox', 'ui.bootstrap'])
```

And finally the relevant parts of index.html

```
<link href="app/views/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-csp.css"></script>
<script src="app/views/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/views/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

I highly appreciate any help on this problem!!

BR,
Martin

Comment: Any error in the javascript console? By the way, you do not have to reference `ui-bootstrap(.min).js` if you reference `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`. This last script contains all ui-bootstrap code with the html templates. Also, it is quite weird to have bower_components under `app/views`

Comment: no error in the JS Console. thanks for the hint with the ui-bootstrap.js. I removed it. Where to the bower components typically go ? I've now added the coding for showing the no result area when no results are found. when i perform the search the no result function is triggered. so it seems that the data is not transfered. I've also changed the Kunde.search from .success to .then. Still getting the same error

Comment: Ideally the `app` folder should contain only app-specific code, and `bower_components` is a sibling folder of `app`

Comment: Related to the problem of the question, the function `searchKunde` is not returning anything, I guess the problem comes from here. Did you tried returning the promise of `Kunde.search` ?

Comment: HI Michael, Problem solved thanks to you! GREAT! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I helped:) I posted the content of the comment as an answer, so as to close the question and in case it could be usefull to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the function `vm.searchKunde`. This function is not returning anything, therefore typeahead values are not populated. Try returning the promise, i.e. :

```
vm.searchKunde = function(val) {
    return Kunde.search ...
}
```